# How to Define a function using method argument in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am using python 2. I imported pyspec library. Say 'scan' is instance type data. Then I can plot:

```
figure()
plot(scan.A,scan.B)
show()
```

This code plot which has 'xvar' as x variables and 'yvar' as y variables. In the 'scan', there are many variables (say A, B, C, etc.).

I tried to define a function:

```
def plotscan(x,y):
    figure()
    plot(scan.x,scan.y)
    show()

plotscan(A,B)
```

However, this code makes error message: name 'A' is not defined

How can I fix this function?

Comment: `spec.A`, like above?

Comment: Carcigenicate/ That's my mistake. I corrected: spec->scan

Comment: Type of 'scan' is instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your goal is, that when you call `plotscan(A, B)` that inside the function x is A an `scan.x` becomes `scan.A`.

The way you do it doesn't work, because the interpreter doesn't know what A and B is and also `scan.x` would be just evaluated to `scan.< value of x >` which doesn't make sense.

The solution is to use `getattr()` (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

```
class Scan(object):
    A = 1
    B = 12
    C = 20

scan = Scan

def plotscan(x,y):
    _x = getattr(scan, x)
    _y = getattr(scan, y)
    print _x, _y


plotscan("A", "B")
```

(I've replaced the call to `plot` with `print` for illustration purposes, so everyone who doesn't have your specific libs installed can try the example)

Here you pass A and B as a string and inside of `plotscan(x, y)` the function `getattr()` returns the value of the attribute of the object `scan` that has the name that is defined by the second parameter.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much and sorry for late reply.

Comment: I also can success using 'plot(eval(' scan.%s' %xvar),eval(' scan.%s' %yvar))' But it's apparent that 'getattr' is more simpler.